# Gigabit Adapter on USB 2.0

Tags: networking, ethernet, samba, gigabit-ethernet, usb-2

I have a USB ethernet adapter on a netbook (Aspire One D250) that I use as a smb server to share files on my LAN. The adapter is 10/100 only, if I buy a 10/100/1000 adapter and use it on USB 2.0, will I see speed improvement even though it obviously isn't going to reach 1000mbps speeds?

Currently, I can copy files from the server between computers at 11~12 Mb/s, and I have tested gigabit before, it goes between 30 and 40 Mb/s.

So, will it get better or stay the same?

Answer (score 2):

Altough you won't be able to get full gigabit ethernet speeds using an USB 2.0 adapter, you should see an improvement. My guess is that you can get up to 25-28 Mbps.

See the comments from actual users of the item you are looking for in  [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/review/R1GRZF376JAFQB/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B003VSTDFG&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=541966&store=pc)

Answer (score 2):

USB 2's maximum speed is 480Mbps, so *in theory*, a gigabit ethernet USB adapter would allow you to utilise speeds above 100Mbps.

Short answer - Yes, its worth a try.